# Set Copyright Info in PDF document, C# or VB net

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, metadata

I am looking to programmatically set the copyright metadata in a bunch of PDF's without using Adobe Acrobat. Is there a free way to do this? (iText7, PDFSharp)

I tried iText7(AGPL) in VB.NET:

```
Dim pdfDoc As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument(New PdfReader(FN))
Dim catalog As PdfDictionary = pdfDoc.GetTrailer()
Dim map As PdfDictionary = catalog.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.Info)
```

And the map key-pairs did not have copyright info. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: 1) The first thing you need is a PDF library.  It sounds like you're using iText7.  2) Next, you need to examine your .pdf to find where the copyright is written (if anywhere).  You tried "catalog.GetAsDictionary()" of "pdfDoc.GetTrailer()".  But it depends on how your particular .pdfs were written.  The "Copyright" text could be anywhere.  3) In any case: iText7 should definitely do the job, once you figure out where the copyright should go.

Comment: paulsm4 - you are correct. I used GetXmpMetadata and found the info I needed for my documents! - Thank You

Comment: @Alan please make that an actual answer to your question.

Comment: I am not seeing the checkmark to accept as answer